# Init Layer in Docker

Tags: docker, storage

Why is there a containerID-init layer created when a container is created from an image in Docker? Couldn't the new container have as parent the image?

Answer (score 5):

Each containers has two layers, one (called the init layer), which is based on an image layer and a child of that which contains the actual container content. The init layer contains a few files that must always exist in Docker containers (e.g. /.dockerinit). 
[Supported Filesystems](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/filesystems/)

The containerID-init layer is the init layer of a container which is based on an image. It add some file into current container,include:

```
    "/dev/pts":         "dir",
    "/dev/shm":         "dir",
    "/proc":            "dir",
    "/sys":             "dir",
    "/.dockerenv":      "file",
    "/etc/resolv.conf": "file",
    "/etc/hosts":       "file",
    "/etc/hostname":    "file",
    "/dev/console":     "file",
    "/etc/mtab":        "/proc/mounts",
```

[code link](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/daemon_unix.go#L689)

Answer (score 2):

`<container>-init` layer exists to create certain must exist files/directories(usually as mountpoints), so that docker can bind mount to these mountpoints without worrying they don't exist.

**NOTE**: init layer is `RO`(READONLY), can not by modified.

These mountpoints are usually empty, and the following explains their purpose:

- `/proc`: in-memory data about processes and system
- `sys`: in-memory system file system
- `/etc/hostname`: container hostname file, each container will have their own hostname, and bind mount to this file
- `/etc/hosts`: hosts file, ip and name mapping
- `/etc/resolv.conf`: DNS-related resolve conf file
- ......